# Approximation error of the delta method: Berry Esseen type bound

Tags: error, delta-method

I'd like to know if there is a literature reference or well-known result in statistics on the estimation error of the (multivariate) delta method, in particular, a Berry-Esseen type bound.

To clarify, consider the univariate case: let $\{X_t\}_{t=1}^n$ be a sequence of zero-mean unit-variance i.i.d. random variables, and let $f(x)$ be a function continuous around $x=0$. Is the following bound known to hold for some constant $B>0$?
\begin{equation}
\left|\Pr\left[\sqrt{n} \; f\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^n X_t\right) \leq x \right] - \Phi\left(\frac{x}{f'(0)}\right)\right| \leq \frac{B}{\sqrt{n}},
\end{equation}

where $\Phi(x)$ is the CDF of the standard Normal distribution.